# IContentRepository vs IContentSoftLinkRepository in Optimizely

Tags: optimizely

In Optimizely, I have come across 2 different interfaces to get a hold of the EPiServer repository - IContentRepository and IContentSoftLinkRepository

Example of IContentRepository :

```
 var repo = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
```

and IContentSoftLinkRepository:

```
var linkRepository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentSoftLinkRepository>();
```

Could somebody explain to me when to use one in front of the other? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IContentRepository` allows you to get content (e.g. pages, blocks, media).

`IContentSoftLinkRepository` allows you to retrieve soft links - i.e. links between content. For example, you can find all content items that link to some other content, such as pages that link to a specific document.